# What are these characters with the "^" symbol being received by my pure TCP web server?

Tags: http, unix, tcp, server, symbols

What are the characters with the "^" symbol being received by my pure TCP web server?

Screenshot from my web server traffic log file with characters I am referring to

[image: Screenshot from my web server traffic log file with characters I am referring to]

**Context:** I created a simple TCP listener socket using C yesterday. I then let it run it on a server exposed to the Internet and recorded all the traffic I received (yes, I know about security issues and so on, but it's an empty sandbox server which I'm purposely using as part of my research). I can see a lot of HTTP GET and POST requests from my logs, but what are these requests I am getting here?

The only results that came up in my searches regarding this "^" symbol is use for "begin with..." in regex, which I don't think is applicable in my situation. (Or is it?)

Comment: These are multibyte characters. Try reading using `od -c`

Comment: [Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to your answers I was able to find this amazing table. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table

Now the next thing I need to figure out is why are random web servers sending me these control sequences...